# Sticky div inside iframe while scrolling parent window

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a webpage with a large iframe overflowing the height of the page. I have a sticky div/header inside the iframe. I would like for the header to "act sticky" when the parent window is being scrolled, is there a way to achieve that? Can I somehow force the parent's view port onto the iframe? Note that I can access the parent window from the iframe if needed (same origin). 
Thank you for any tips!

Comment: You could 'stickify' your entire iframe element

Comment: I forgot to mention I need to scroll the iframe as well, since it is large. But i would like to scroll it by using the parent's scrollbar so I don't have two scrollbars in case there are other elements on the parent page.

Comment: what about `html, body { height: 100vh; overflow:hidden; }` on the parent window? That would remove the scrollbar.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not any good way to do this. A JS sticky code is laggy at best, and there's no way to position an element inside the iframe related to the parent window. The only solution is to clone the sticky element to the parent page, and position it as fixed to the desired place.

Comment: @roast. I am facing the exact usecase you have mentioned in the question. Could you please share how you have resolved this?. Thanks/

Comment: Exact same problem here; any improvement in the past 4 years?